# Arduino unable to match Char data

Tags: c++, if-statement, arduino, char

I have an Arduino web server project going. Right now I'm trying to parse url parameters. For instance, I wish to make a GET request to http://(localip)/info and then have the "info" returned and displayed.

I don't know if I've been staring at the screen too long today, but I can't seem to match a simple char which is a single space... This shouldn't be complex in the slightest! All the advice I've found do not work. Yet, I need to break the loop on a space because that is an indicator where my url parameter ends. I want to be able to use /info as well as /something else.

```
char *data = (char *) Ethernet::buffer + pos;
String buff;
for (int x = 5; x<15; x++) {
  Serial.print(x); Serial.print(" - |"); Serial.print(data[x]); Serial.println("|");
  if ((data[x] == " ") || (data[x] == char(" ")) || (strcmp(data[x], " ") == 0)) {
    x = 999;
    break;
  } else {
    buff += data[x];
  }
  delay(5);
}
```

Serial monitor output. It should break on #9 and buff should equal just "info"

5 - |i|
6 - |n|
7 - |f|
8 - |o|

### 9 - | |

10 - |H|
11 - |T|
12 - |T|
13 - |P|
14 - |/|
buff -> info HTTP/

Comment: You're confusing characters and strings.

Comment: Hi Ignacio, do you have a suggestion to correct my mistake or is it not possible to compare chars?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (data[x] == 0x20 || (isspace(data[x]))) 
{
    //is a white space 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using double quote marks (") in your char comparisons.  In C++, the double quote marks are used to define strings, not characters.  Characters are defined using single quotes (')

testing for a space:  `if (c == ' ')`.

Unlike strings, you can also use chars in switch statements:

```
switch (c)
{
case 'a': case 'A':
    Serial.println("I've got an A!!");
    break;
}
```